# Does a Button onClick create and destroy the view within the event of clicking?

Tags: android, button, onclick, listener, countdowntimer

I have an Android app that should emulate a timer, the problem is that when I tap the button that should start the timer, the `CountDownTimer` immediatly triggers the onFinish method, resulting in a log entry saying that the timer has finished and showing a toast on the phone. Dows the button `onClick` call create and destroy the view within the click event?

This is the method called by the button:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        timerValue = newVal*1000;
    }
        });

        new CountDownTimer(timerValue, 1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                Log.i("robeh accadono", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Il timer è arrivato alla fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("Fatto!", "finito");

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

It seems that when the button is pressed the `timerValue` variable isn't assigned at all

Comment: did you try using a debugger with break point to figure out whats hapenning?

Comment: Yes, and it is like if it resets the timerValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this piece of code from your click event and use it before the button click code snippet

```
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        timerValue = newVal*1000;
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought that it should have been inside the onClick so it does take the right value, goin to try it now

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nicola just change your code to this:

public void onClick(View v){
        int timerValue = numberPicker.getValue() * 1000;

```
    new CountDownTimer(timerValue, 1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Log.e("robeh accadono", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Il timer è arrivato alla fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Fatto!", "finito");

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Hope it helps!!!